# Facing Issue in using Asp.net Web Api with details given below:

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, controller

I Created the Web Api application with two Controllers and the first one is `HomeController` in which I created the action named `ApiDataView` and create the view of this action and calling the another action named `GetNames` in which I created in another Controller named `APITESTController` and I am calling this `GetNames` `List<string>` in `ApiDataView` View but On button click I cannot get the values of this `GetNames` action.

**My Code:**

`Home` Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace My_Work.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ApiDataView()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

`APITest` Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace My_Work.Controllers
{
    public class APITestController : ApiController
    {
        public List<string> GetNames()
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Zeeshan", "Uzair", "Nouman" };
            return names;
        }
    }
}
```

`ApiDataView` View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>APIDataView</title>
    <script> src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Show Name" />
        <ul id="nl">
            <li>ABC</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#nl").empty();
        $.getJSON("api/APITest/GetNames", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (id,val) {
                $("#nl").append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`WebApiConfig` App_Start Folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace My_Work
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            var xmlType =
                config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
                config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(xmlType);
        }
    }
}
```

`RouteConfig` App_Start Folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace My_Work
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ApiDataView", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the code where I am getting `GetNames` action values:**

```
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#nl").empty();
        $.getJSON("api/APITest/GetNames", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (id,val) {
                $("#nl").append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**and now On button click I cannot get the values of `GetNames` action. Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you have given is relative means it will append your path  "api/APITest/GetNames" after the current URL so the request path created is **"/Home/api/APITest/GetNames"** which do not exist that's why you're getting 404 error (check in browser's console). To fix this, give your path like this **"/api/APITest/GetNames"** to make it absolute means start from **"/api"**.

```
$.getJSON("/api/APITest/GetNames", function (data) {});
```